# How can I route different traffic over different interfaces (routes) by protocol?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have two different WAN interfaces in a Linux (iptables) router. How could I achieve a situation where different traffic is routed over different interfaces, depending on the protocol (destination TCP port)? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the feature you are looking for is named Policy Routing. Have a look at http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html (second example)