# Multiple interfaces: route packets to specific interface

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, route, multiple-instances

I have 2 internet connections on my network. My router is running Debian.
eth0 is my network (192.168.0.0/16).
eth1 and eth2 are connected to 2 different internet providers (with dynamic IP).

Here is a small drawing of my configuration

```
PC1 ---|                  |-eth1- DynIP provider 1
PC2 ---|-eth0- Router --- |
PCn ---|                  |-eth2- DynIP provider 2
```

I'm trying to configure it as follow:
I want all packets by default to go via eth1. All packets coming from a PC having address 192.168.2.0/24 to go via eth2.

After looking for a while and posting on other forums I already have the following (in my rc.local file):

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

with route table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.4.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.1.50     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.0.4.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I tried to play with `route` and `ip route` but I cannot find it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing decisions are based on destination addresses. If you want to route traffic based on the source address you need to configure policy-based routing. Have a look at:

http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html

I answered these similar questions a few weeks ago:

[How can I route different traffic over different interfaces (routes) by protocol?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426806/how-can-i-route-different-traffic-over-different-interfaces-routes-by-protocol)

[Using iptables to forward traffic destined for specific ip via specific interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/429747/using-iptables-to-forward-traffic-destined-for-specific-ip-via-specific-interfac)

Comment: It is working. But when I watch netstat -i, it looks like both interfaces are receiving packets.

Comment: it is working now. I had to remove the default route from the main route table.